# Can POI or docx4j read Word docs that are password-protected?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I'm having an issue with POI that I'd like some help with.

I have a personal journal that I've kept for years by making daily entries into a Word .doc per month that's stored in a year folder.  I add a password to open each one, so they're all encrypted.

I want to use Lucene to index the entire collection to allow better searching (e.g. "What day and year did I last write about how much I like oatmeal?").

The first step was to use POI to read a Word .doc, but I can't get off the dime because it can't read my encrypted file.

I've written this class:

```
package model;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.DocumentProperties;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Decryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.dev.POIFSLister;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * JournalReader class that's the heart of my efforts to finally read, parse, index, and search my journal.
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 8/19/12 3:48 PM
 */
public class JournalReader {
    public static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(JournalReader.class);
    public static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "journal";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                POIFSLister.viewFile(args[0], true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public List<JournalEntry> readEntries(File journalFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        List<JournalEntry> journalEntries = new LinkedList<JournalEntry>();
        if (journalFile != null) {
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(journalFile));
            // Exception is thrown after info line is executed.
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
            decryptor.verifyPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
            HWPFDocument journalDocument = new HWPFDocument(decryptor.getDataStream(fs));
            DocumentProperties documentProperties = journalDocument.getDocProperties();
        }
        return journalEntries;
    }
}
```

I have a JUnit test to try it out:

```
import model.JournalEntry;
import model.JournalReader;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * JournalReaderTest JUnit test for JournalReader
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 8/19/12 8:46 PM
 */
public class JournalReaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testReadEntries() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        JournalReader journalReader = new JournalReader();
        String journalFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Michael\\Documents\\Stuff To Back Up\\Journal\\1994\\AUG94.doc";
        File journalFile = new File(journalFilePath);
        List<JournalEntry> journalEntries = journalReader.readEntries(journalFile);
        Assert.assertNotNull(journalEntries);
        Assert.assertTrue(journalEntries.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

When I run the JUnit test, I get this stack trace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7540 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 122.29\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 122.29\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 122.29\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\alt-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\out\test\diary-index;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\out\production\diary-index;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-io-2.3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\antlr-runtime-3.3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-io-1.3.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\docx4j-2.8.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\fop-1.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\itext-2.1.7.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\jaxb-svg11-1.0.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\jaxb-xslfo-1.0.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-3.8.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\wmf2svg-0.9.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\lib\xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar;F:\Projects\Java\diary-index\test-lib\junit-4.10.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 JournalReaderTest
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [consoleAppender] to category [root].

java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo"
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.getEntry(DirectoryNode.java:375)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocumentInputStream(DirectoryNode.java:177)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:39)
    at model.JournalReader.readEntries(JournalReader.java:43)
    at JournalReaderTest.testReadEntries(JournalReaderTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

The POI docs and javadocs have been useless.  I'm frustrated enough where I've thought about switching to docx4j.  It would mean translating all my .doc files to .docx (after suitable backup, of course).

I'd like to know if anyone has had any success using docx4j to read encrypted, password-protected files.  Anyone?  I'd just like an affirmative answer to tell me that it's worth pressing on.

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong with POI I'd be glad to know that, too.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just load up your .doc, and re-save it without the password? POI should then be able to load it just fine

Comment: I want to retain the password; there are a lot of files.  Why should I have to alter every one because of poorly written software?

Comment: So, some open source software, which has kindly been given away to the world for free, which you have paid nothing for, and you've not contributed to, doesn't have all the features you'd like it to, and that's somehow the project's fault?

Comment: Fair enough.  It's been around for a very, very long time.  It must not be very active anymore.  I'd rather just find something like docx4j and move on.    Do you contribute more than sparkling comments here, Gagravarr?

Comment: I deduce from the few answers you've provided here in the last year that you may have an association with POI.  Is that true?  If so, please do state it.  Maybe you should consider me a potential customer and get on that defect.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure: I work on docx4j**

docx4j's OpcPackage contains:

```
/**
 * Convenience method to create a WordprocessingMLPackage
 * or PresentationMLPackage
 * from an existing File (.docx/.docxm, .ppxtx or Flat OPC .xml).
 *
 * @param docxFile
 *            The docx file
 * @param password
 *            The password, if the file is password protected (compound)
 *            
 * @Since 2.8.0           
 */ 
public static OpcPackage load(final java.io.File docxFile, String password) throws Docx4JException
```

which ought to take care of the password-protected part.

I haven't played much with encryption/decryption of docx files myself.

Comment: Great, I'll try it out as soon as I can and let you know.  (It might not be until the weekend, so sit tight waiting for the vote.)  If it works, I'll gladly accept this answer.  I especially appreciate the docx4j disclosure.  I like both the expertise and the honesty.

Comment: JasonPlutext, you got me one step closer, but I need help to take another step.  If you're watching, I'll post another docx4j question.  I hope you'll answer.

Comment: Wait - the doc didn't keep the password when I converted it.  I was able to read it successfully, but then it failed when I added the password.  Any advice?

Comment: Currently the method save(java.io.File docxFile, String password) does nothing if password is not null. That's a TODO (and your question was about read, not write).  If POI can't do the write for us, then at least http://code.google.com/p/ooxmlcrypto/source/browse/trunk/OfficeCrypto/OfficeCrypto.cs illustrates what needs to be done.

Comment: I converted it manually using "save as" in Word itself for one document.  My use case is still the same: it failed on read until I removed the encryption.